# How to get ClientId in a custom action in custom ViewService in IdentityServer3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I am customizing [this MVC ViewService example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/MVC%20ViewService) of IdentityServer3.
I am trying to add a custom action in LogonWorkflowController where data will be submitted by post request from Login page.

I added a new route in RouteConfig

```
 routes.MapRoute(name: "ResetPasswordSend", url: "send/me/smth",
            defaults: new { controller = "LogonWorkflow", action = "Send" });
```

and I added a new Action in LogonWorkflowController

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Send(MyCustomModell model)
    {
      <get ClientId?>
      ....
    }
```

Is it possible to find out ClientId parameter to be able to create a custom answer based this on ClientId?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're getting to the page from IdSvr (for example from a link on the login page), then IdSvr will pass your page an id param. From this id param you can use the OWIN extensions to lookup the SignInMessage that represents the pending sign in and that contains the client id.

Comment: If you are talking about SignInMessage object, then only "created" param is passed. Is it the Id param you are talking about?

Comment: If you don't have a ClientId then the user is logging it without going to a client first (e.g. they tried to access the client permissions page).

Comment: Sorry, probably I got it wrong. In the Login action I can get ClientId `public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, SignInMessage message) {    
            var customerCLientId = message.ClientId; <more code>}`. I also can send it to the Login View and send it back with every request which user makes. Is it safe to do? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not following.

Comment: @BrockAllen, Kindly explain further how to use OWIN extensions to lookup SignInMessage. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54078157/how-to-get-environment-from-global-asax-to-derive-signinmessage-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question (with reference to the code [MVC ViewService example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/MVC%20ViewService)):
When Login action of LogonWorkflowController is called, we can get client ID from the message variable and pass it into ViewBag.

```
ViewBag.ClientId =  message.ClientId;
```

Then using a hidden field in the Login view or using javascript post we can send this clientId to the required post action. So, client ID becomes available in the post action from the Model.

I don't need to implement this anymore, but I think this is the way I could do it. Just be aware that this request can be faked, so nothing important should rely on the received clientID.